# перемещение элемента по координатам с массива

Tags: javascript

как сделать, что бы при нажатии на кнопку repeat повторялось движение мяча, по координатам с массива

```js
const theThing = document.querySelector("#thing");
const container = document.querySelector("#contentContainer");
 
container.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);



var x = document.querySelector("#contentContainer");
var offsetX = x.offsetLeft;
var offsetY = x.offsetTop;
x.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

var coords = [];

function handleClick(e) {
  mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);  
  coords.push([mouseX, mouseY]);
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You have clicked at: " + JSON.stringify(coords);
}


function repeat(){

   for (let i=0; i < coords.length; i++){
    
   }

}

function getClickPosition(e) {
    let parentPosition = getPosition(e.currentTarget);
    let xPosition = e.clientX - parentPosition.x - (theThing.clientWidth / 2);
    let yPosition = e.clientY - parentPosition.y - (theThing.clientHeight / 2);
     
    theThing.style.left = xPosition + "px";
    theThing.style.top = yPosition + "px";
}



function getPosition(el) {
  let xPos = 0;
  let yPos = 0;
 
  while (el) {
    if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
      
      let xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      let yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 
      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
    } else {
      
      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    }
 
    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFF;

  
}
#contentContainer {
  width: 90%;
  height: 580px;
  border: 5px black solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(72, 161, 76);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#thing {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  transition: left .5s ease-in, top .5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
      <div id="contentContainer">
    <img src='https://js.cx/clipart/ball.svg' id="thing"><img>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button onclick="repeat()">repeat</button>
  <br>
  <p id="results">result</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот такое предложение:

```
function repeat(){
   var a = [...coords]; 
   var i = setInterval(function() {
        relocate(...a.shift())
        !a.length && clearInterval(i)
   }, 1000)
}

function relocate(x, y){
    theThing.style.left = x + "px";
    theThing.style.top = y + "px";
}
```

```js
const theThing = document.querySelector("#thing");
const container = document.querySelector("#contentContainer");
 
container.addEventListener("click", getClickPosition, false);

var x = document.querySelector("#contentContainer");
var offsetX = x.offsetLeft;
var offsetY = x.offsetTop;
x.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

var coords = [];

function handleClick(e) {
  mouseX = parseInt(e.clientX - offsetX);
  mouseY = parseInt(e.clientY - offsetY);  
  coords.push([mouseX, mouseY]);
  document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "You have clicked at: " + JSON.stringify(coords);
}

function repeat(){
   var a = coords.slice(0); 
   console.log(a)
   var i = setInterval(function() {
        relocate(...a.shift())
        !a.length && clearInterval(i)
   }, 1000)
}

function getClickPosition(e) {
    let parentPosition = getPosition(e.currentTarget);
    let xPosition = e.clientX - parentPosition.x - (theThing.clientWidth / 2);
    let yPosition = e.clientY - parentPosition.y - (theThing.clientHeight / 2);
    relocate(xPosition,yPosition);
}

function relocate(x, y){
    theThing.style.left = x + "px";
    theThing.style.top = y + "px";
}

function getPosition(el) {
  let xPos = 0;
  let yPos = 0;
 
  while (el) {
    if (el.tagName == "BODY") {
      
      let xScroll = el.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      let yScroll = el.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;
 
      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - xScroll + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - yScroll + el.clientTop);
    } else {
      
      xPos += (el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft + el.clientLeft);
      yPos += (el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop + el.clientTop);
    }
 
    el = el.offsetParent;
  }
  return {
    x: xPos,
    y: yPos
  };
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
#contentContainer {
  width: 90%;
  height: 580px;
  border: 5px black solid;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgb(72, 161, 76);
  cursor: pointer;
}
#thing {
  position: relative;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  transition: left .5s ease-in, top .5s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div id="contentContainer">
    <img src='https://js.cx/clipart/ball.svg' id="thing"><img>
  </div>
  <br>
  <button onclick="repeat()">repeat</button>
  <br>
  <p id="results">result</p>
```

Comment: Спасибо работает)

Comment: @ВладАпальков всегда пожалуйста, только изначальное положение тоже нужно добавить в массив =)